# ggplot: sums per time unit (e.g. an hour) without group_by() and summarise()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following sample data. It's a list of interviews with a date variable indicating when each interview was completed.

```r
n <- 10000

df <- data.frame(
  year = rep(2020,n),
  month = sample(1:12, n, replace = T),
  day = sample(1:28, n, replace = T),
  hour = sample(0:23, n, replace = T),
  min = sample(0:59, n, replace = T),
  sec = sample(0:59, n, replace = T)
)

df

df %>% mutate(dt = make_datetime(year, month, day, hour, min, sec)) %>%
  group_by(format(dt, "%Y/%m/%d")) %>%
  summarise(n = n())
```

My goal is to have a line plot (e.g. number of completed interviews (Y) per week (X) ) where I can easily change the x-axis (e.g. if I'd like to plot the number of interviews per MONTH or MINUTES instead of weeks).

So my question is: Do I always have to use `group_by(<TIME UNIT>)`, then `summarise(n = n())` and finally plot it or is there a way to **directly** calculate/plot the number of interviews per time unit?

```
Interviews
^
|
|                     .
|       .  .           
| ... .. .. ...  ..... .....
|.   .         ..
|
|
|__________________________________> Time
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stat_bin` to automatically bin the counts, with a line geom. The bin widths have to be given as a numeric value of seconds, but this is straightforward since you are using `lubridate`. Here we'll group by weeks:

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(dt = make_datetime(year, month, day, hour, min, sec)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = dt)) + 
  stat_bin(geom = "line", binwidth = as.numeric(seconds(weeks(1))))
```

[image]

Here by days:

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(dt = make_datetime(year, month, day, hour, min, sec)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = dt)) + 
  stat_bin(geom = "line", binwidth = as.numeric(seconds(days(1))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the number of interviews with the `stat`-argument in `geom_line` and the time unit in `x`.

```
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)

df2 <- df %>% 
mutate(dt = make_datetime(year, month, day, hour, min, sec))

# days
ggplot(df2, aes(x = format(dt, "%d"), group = 1)) +
  geom_line(stat = "count")

# months
ggplot(df2, aes(x = format(dt, "%m"), group = 1)) +
  geom_line(stat = "count")

# weekday
ggplot(df2, aes(x = format(dt, "%w"), group = 1)) +
  geom_line(stat = "count")

# week of year 
ggplot(df2, aes(x = format(dt, "%W"), group = 1)) +
  geom_line(stat = "count")
```